# Converting column with nested jsons

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df:

```
ID    Message
1     {"user":user10, "message":{"sender":"k3532", "card":87876}}
2     {"user":user14, "message":{"sender":"hg769", "card":6434363654}}
3     {"user":user22, "message":{"sender":"gjhyj5", "card":87676876, "allowed":true}}
```

which you can create via

```
df = structure(list(ID = 1:3, Message = c("{\"user\":\"user10\", \"message\":{\"sender\":\"k3532\", \"card\":87876}}", 
                                     "{\"user\":\"user14\", \"message\":{\"sender\":\"hg769\", \"card\":6434363654}}", 
                                     "{\"user\":\"user22\", \"message\":{\"sender\":\"gjhyj5\", \"card\":87676876, \"allowed\":true}}"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.frame"
))
```

I want to parse those jsons in column Message and turn them into columns. I do this with json from first row:

```
df_col <- df[1,]$Message %>% 
  fromJSON() 
df_col <- enframe(unlist(df_col))
df_col <- setNames(data.frame(as.list(df_col$value)), df_col$name)
```

And i get dataframe, which looks like this:

```
user      message.sender  message.card
user10      k3532            87876
```

where "user"      "message.sender"  "message.card" are columns. Now i want to do that with every json in every row and bind with original dataframe. So, desired result must look like this:

```
ID    name    user       message.sender   message.card    message.allowed
1     value   user10       k3532            87876            NA
2     value   user14       hg769            6434363654       NA
3     value   user22       gjhyj5           87676876         TRUE
```

How could I write that function?

Comment: @RonakShah its different cause its about binding data frames, not parsing. Here i already provide code for parsing (not in a way that was offered) and a question is about binding a data frame that i get from parsing with original data frame

Comment: @RonakShah that a solution must include this code ```df_col <- df[1,]$Message %>% 
  fromJSON() 
df_col <- enframe(unlist(df_col))
df_col <- setNames(data.frame(as.list(df_col$value)), df_col$name)```. its very important. I don't ask how to parse, i ask how to bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the solution has to use your current method you can prepare a function with it :

```
get_data <- function(message) {
  df_col <- message %>% jsonlite::fromJSON
  df_col <- tibble::enframe(unlist(df_col))
  df_col <- setNames(data.frame(as.list(df_col$value)), df_col$name)
  df_col
}
```

This works with one value like this :

```
get_data(df$Message[1])
    user message.sender message.card
1 user10          k3532        87876
```

and for all the `Message` values you can use `purrr::map_dfr` :

```
purrr::map_dfr(df$Message, get_data)

#    user message.sender message.card message.allowed
#1 user10          k3532        87876            <NA>
#2 user14          hg769   6434363654            <NA>
#3 user22         gjhyj5     87676876            TRUE
```